# Using Knockout JS with CSS to fade between classes bg colors

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel observable value called **changed** which gets set after a postback if the row in question has changed. Then I set a timer to set **changed** back to false after so many seconds. That all works fine so the row goes green when **changed** is set and back to the default after that.

But I would like the transition between the bg colors to fade rather than straight swap. The tr definition is below.

```
            <tr data-bind="css: { greenBg: changed() == true, dataRowEven: $index() % 2 }" class="dataRow">
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Cheers
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using CSS3 [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to provide this feature to users with up to date browsers, letting things gracefully degrade for older browsers? You could use CSS like this:

```
tr { 
    background-color: lightgray;   
    -moz-transition: 3s;
    -webkit-transition: 3s;
    -o-transition: 3s;
    transition: 3s;
}

tr.dataRowEven { 
    background-color: gray; 
}

tr.greenBg { 
    background-color: green;
}
```

See this in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQHC/).

Alternatively, if you need to provide this feature to older browsers as well, it may be best not to use the basic `css` binding, but [create a custom handler](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQHC/) that uses [jQuery `animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to change the color after a certain period has elapsed.